# How to recording music playing in the background not microphone

Tags: java, android

In my application, I have to record sound with music. When I click on record button , music starts and recording is starting too. User will sing the song and this song will record with music.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, It's looks like mixing two audio's, you don't have to do anything with your music, just record the voice and after that mix it with the music.

Comment: my question is we want to record only internal sound not external.

Comment: What you mean by Internal sound? As of I can understand User Voice is external source of audio stream and you have to record it from Microphone. If I'm wrong then please update your question with more detailed explanation.